# How do I renew a spring session?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, session

I have a web application running spring MVC on Websphere, and I am trying to implement a session expiration confirm. I now where to redirect if they choose to log out but I don't know how to renew a session if the choose to do that.

So far I understand I am using jQuery and ajax to send a request somewhere to the server but  do not know where (the url), nor the arguments or the expected response. Does anyone know have a general idea how I find this out? Is it a standard function of spring session or am I going to have to write a custom function to fix this?

Comment: Alright to maybe simplify, I want to use jQuery or JavaScript to re-validate the user session when an expiration warning pops up. We are working on a Websphere 8.5 server with a spring MVC framework. I am looking for how a tell the server to re-validate the session.

Comment: After some more reading I now kind of understand that just making an ajax call will revalidate the session. but I am worried that I may screw up the current view with a behind the scenes ajax call can anyone give an example of an ajax call that honestly does nothing?

Comment: Another thought should I just have the page refresh instead? Will that reset the timeout? Input may be lost but if a user is inactive for near twenty minutes on our site then I doubt they were going to submit their action in the first place. SO would a page refresh work?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out by combining information from multiple sources out on there. I came up with the following code:

```
    function timeoutMessage(){
        var popupdate = new Date();
        var renewSession = confirm('Your Session is about to expire!\n\nYou will be logged out in 2 minute.\nDo you want to stay signed in?');
        if(renewSession){
            var response = new Date();
            if(response - popupdate > 120000){
                alert("Response took too long, current session has ended. \nRedirecting to login.");
            }else{
                pingServer();
                resetTimeout();
            }
        }else{
             window.location.href = "{app logout url}";
        }
    }

    function pingServer(){
        jQuery.ajax({url: "{valid server page url}",type: "HEAD",complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {}});
    }

     function resetTimeout(){
         window.setTimeout(function(){timeoutMessage();},1080000);
     }

    $(document).ready(function()
        resetTimeout(); 
    });
```

The function sets a timer that coincides with two minutes before the session timeout. Most sites will offer most of the above code but what that in the pingServer() function; in order to extend the session on the server you can send a simple ajax call of type 'HEAD' to the server without interrupting the applications primary flow. It is seen as an action by the server toward the session and thus resets/renews the session's timeout. You don't need to do anything with the server response as seen in the code; just as long as you send the request the session timeout will be reset/renewed.

I hope this helps. It took me a while to completely piece together.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set a bigger number for `max_inactive_interval` so the session will last longer?

Spring Session automatically renews if the user is active. Take a look at the table created by Spring Session for storing the session data: there is a column `max_inactive_interval` which basically means that the session will only expire if the user is not active for that interval of time.

[image]